# Evolution: Scroll to bottom of inbox per default

Tags: gnome, gnome3, evolution

I run Debian Wheezy with a Gnome 3 desktop. I migrated from Thunderbird to Evolution to manage my e-mails.

I have my inbox configured to show the newest mails on the bottom. However, when Evolution starts it always shows me the top of the inbox (where my oldest e-mails are).

How can I change this behavior so that Evolution automatically scrolls to the bottom of my inbox?

P.S.: I wouldn't mind to "flip" the inbox, so that the newest mails are on top. However with "stacked conversations" this is very confusing in Evolution, as the newest mail of each stack is on the bottom of the stack, but newer stacks are above older stacks...